# What's a faster alternative to PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas, opencv

I'm trying to display a video, and using the examples/solutions to the question on how to play a video on Tkinter don't seemt to yeild smooth and fast rendering.

For example:

```
frame = self.vid_cap.read()
frame = cv2.resize(frame, (696, 486))
frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

self.latest_img_ = Image.fromarray(frame)
self.latest_img_ = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.latest_img_)

self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=self.latest_img_)
```

The above code works, but video is too slow, even when using something like `self.canvas.after(1, self.video_loop_)`. After some benchmarking, it turned out that the following line:

```
self.latest_img_ = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.latest_img_)
```

Takes 9ms ~ 100ms regardless when I run the code on my quad-core mac or 12-core rig, while the entire code above it (from capturing, and until converting the numpy array to an image) takes 0ms to 1ms only.

What could be a faster alternative to `ImageTk.PhotoImage`?

Comment: Are you creating a new image every 1ms or reusing the same canvas object? It makes a big difference.

Comment: @HenryYik I think nothing is being reused (except for Canvas object). The partial code I included in my question is almost the same that I havae in my project. Can you share an example on how to reuse the image object?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Tkinter itself should not be used to display video, instead, try looking at integrating other widgets

Comment: With that size image, the `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` takes 823 microseconds on my MacBook Pro, i.e. less than a millisecond. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep a reference of the `canvas` object and modify it instead of creating new objects every time. To do that you can first create a placeholder by passing `image=None`. Below is a minimum sample:

```
import tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
        self.streaming_image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=None)

    def show_frame(self):
        _, frame = self.vid_cap.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (696, 486))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = Image.fromarray(frame)
        self.latest_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.streaming_image, image=self.latest_img)
        self.after(10, self.show_frame)

    def start_video(self, path=None):
        self.vid_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
        self.show_frame()


root = GUI()
root.start_video("your_path_here")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. I ran your code as a test and it works perfectly fine, but when I tried to use the same solution on my app it was still slow. Eventually, I realized the only difference is that I'm using a custom VideoCapture that uses a thread/queue, when I replaced that with the cv2.VideoCapture it played the video very fast.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense to me, because when I measure execution time, only `ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)` takes long and it's not inside any new threads. But that's for another question, I believe.

Comment: actually now when I set the width and height on the canvas, it does become slow again. :( Do you get this issue too on your end if you replace `self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)` with `self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=696, height=486)`?

Comment: Nope, I don't see a change in performance after setting height and width.